# Lost ability to connect remotely to Firebird database after upgrading to Ubuntu Server 13.10

Tags: server, 13.10, remote, database

I decided to upgrade my Ubuntu server from 13.04 to 13.10.
When finished, I lost the ability to remotely connect to my Firebird 2.5 database (works locally / 127.0.0.1)!

I didn't change anything in the configuration and I don't understand why this has happened.

I use Webmin remotely to configure the firewall (IpTables) and the other resources in the server. I have several other services that work correctly!

Comment: Solved: The upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 set RemoteBindAddress to 'localhost'.

Comment: Please never post resolving advice as a comment.  If you want to share a solution, please post an answer with the intent to educate future researchers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a Debian/Ubuntu change , Firebird should be secure by default (port should be closed by default for the outside world)

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=702971

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, this is due to xinet

From a fresh install:

```
sudo su
apt-get install xinetd
apt-get install python-software-properties
add-apt-repository ppa:mapopa
apt-get update
apt-get install firebird2.5-classic                 
netstat -an | grep 3050             #shows the problem: not binding to 0.0.0.0
nano /etc/firebird/2.5/firebird.conf
    #comment out all RemoteBindAddress = XXXX
nano  /etc/xinetd.d/firebird25
    #set  bind                    = 0.0.0.0
/etc/init.d/xinetd restart
dpkg-reconfigure firebird2.5-classic
netstat -an | grep 3050             #shows the fixed as binding to 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove installed firebird

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge firebird*
   ```
2. Install Xinetd

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xinetd
   ```
3. Download http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-linux-amd64/2.5.2-Release/FirebirdCS-2.5.2.26540-0.amd64.tar.gz/download

   Then unzipped folder:

   ```
   sudo ./install.sh
   ```

So it worked for me!